# Jquery masonary layout like this

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

Hi guys i am trying to integrate jquery masonary with worpress.
i have this code

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var $container = $('#portfolio');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $container.masonry( { columnWidth: 50,itemSelector: '.portfolio' } );
    });
});
```

I am using canvas child theme and it is not resizing images
[image]

i want to look layout like this 
[image]

Any suggestions
Html is like this 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the option you are seeking is "columnWidth".

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth

```
{
columnWidth: 100
}
```

However, if that layout is all you need, I don't think you require Masonary.js. You can do it simply using floats.